# QCD Color Structure relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, color-charge

i want to proof the following relation :

\begin{equation}
t^a t^b \otimes t^a t^b = \frac{2}{N_C} \delta^{ab} \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} - \frac{1}{N_C} t^a \otimes t^a
\end{equation}

Right now I calculated the second term, but still have problems to get to the Casimir operator $C_F$ of the first term.

Knowing $t^a = \frac{\lambda^a}{2}$ and $\lambda^a\lambda^b = \frac{2}{N_C}\delta^{ab} + d^{abc}\lambda^c + i f^{abc}\lambda^c$ yields

\begin{equation}
  t^a t^b \otimes t^a t^b = \frac{1}{16}\lambda^a \lambda^b \otimes \lambda^a \lambda^b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  = \frac{1}{16} \left[ \frac{2}{N_C}\delta^{ab} + d^{abc}\lambda^c + i f^{abc}\lambda^c \right] \otimes \left[ \frac{2}{N_C}\delta^{ab} + d^{abc}\lambda^c + i f^{abc}\lambda^c \right]
\end{equation}
I am hopefully right, that $f^{aab} = d^{aab} = 0$, thus
\begin{equation}
  = \frac{1}{16} \left[ \frac{4}{N_C^2} \delta^{ab} \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} - \frac{4}{N} \lambda^c \otimes \lambda^c + i d^{abc}f^{abc} \lambda^c \otimes \lambda^c + i f^{abc} d^{abc} \lambda^c \otimes \lambda^c \right]
\end{equation}
where I used $f^{abc}f^{abc} = N$ and $d^{abc}d^{abc} = \left( N - \frac{4}{N} \right)$.

The Casimir operator is defined as 
\begin{equation}
  \frac{N_C^2 -1}{2N_C} \equiv C_F
\end{equation}

And as I said I do not know how to get to the result of the first equation by plugging in the Casimir operator. I have a strong guess that if I would know how to deal with the terms $i d^{abc}f^{abc} \lambda^c \otimes \lambda^c$ the result will be obvious, but until know I appreciate every help.

Comment: There's some inconsistency in the notation going on here - do you sum over repeated indices or not? If the answer is "sometimes", you should write explicit sums where you do so.

Comment: Yeah I was summing wrong over the $\delta^{ab}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebodys interested in the solution I just solved it myself :P
﻿﻿﻿\begin{equation}
                  \begin{split}
                          t^a t^b \otimes t^a t^b &= \frac{1}{16} [\lambda^a \lambda^b   \otimes \lambda^a \lambda^b] \\
                          &= \frac{1}{16} \left[\frac{2}{N_c}\delta^{ab} \mathbb{1} +   d^{abc} \lambda_c + if^{abc} \lambda^c\right] \otimes \left[\frac{2}{N_c}\delta^{ab}   \mathbb{1} + d^{abc} \lambda_c + if^{abc} \lambda^c\right] \\
                          &= \frac{1}{16}\left[\frac{4}{N_c^2}(N_c^2-1)\mathbb{1}\otimes \mathbb{1} + d^{abc}d^{abc}\lambda^c\otimes\lambda^c - f^{abc}f^{abc} \lambda^c \otimes \lambda^c\right] \\
                          &= \frac{1}{16} \left[\frac{4C_F}{N_c} \mathbb{1} \otimes\mathbb{1} + \left(N_c - \frac{4}{N_c} - N_c \right) \right] \\
                          &= \frac{C_F}{4N_c}\mathbb{1}\otimes\mathbb  {1} - \frac{1}{N_c}t^a \otimes t^a
                  \end{split}
          \end{equation}